# Why scoped service can be resolved from singleton in docker container?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I have my app with two services (singleton and scoped) and /test endpoint, singleton resolves scoped service and using it to do some logic. I know that it's an antipattern, but it's just for example.

**Prorgam.cs**

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddLogging();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<SingletonService>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ScopedService>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/test", (SingletonService service) => service.MakeTest());

app.Run();
```

**Services**

```
public class ScopedService
{
    public string GetTestString() => "test success";
}
```

```
public class SingletonService(ScopedService service, ILogger<SingletonService> logger)
{
    public void MakeTest()
    {
        var testString = service.GetTestString();
        logger.LogInformation("Success?: {SuccessMessage}", testString);
    }
}
```

## Now two cases:

### First

Just start the app - you'll get Unhandled exception.

```
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: WebApplication1.SingletonService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: WebApplication1.SingletonService': Cannot consume scoped service 'WebApplication1.ScopedService' from singleton 'WebApplication1.SingletonService'.)
```

It's ok - as it should work.

### Second

Create docker image with `dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 /t:PublishContainer -c Release`
and start it. It'll start, more - it'll give log that I made in service logic.
[image: example of app log in docker container]

**The question is** - why it's working like that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try calling `IHostBuilder.UseDefaultServiceProvider()` and passing in an instance of `ServiceProviderOptions` and retry this? 
```builder.Host.UseDefaultServiceProvider((build) => new ServiceProviderOptions { ValidateOnBuild = true, ValidateScopes = true });```

I had tried making a web application and adding Docker support via VS and it did throw the exception using your command, too.

Comment: Yes, with that command container works as local app. But main question - why containered app acting like that with default settings.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see this earlier. Well, I suppose you found the answer to that already. :)

Comment: Np, yes, I figured it out, too bad it's not on the surface. At least now there will be this theme on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is - by default publish disables 'isDev' and making environment acting like Production layer. Therefore we have no scopes validation.

If the Scoped service resolves from singleton, then Scoped remains Scoped, But for Singleton, an instance will be added that will not be deleted by the garbage collector, respectively, all other dependencies are the same

The way to avoid this is to use the following code in Program.cs

```cs
builder.Host.UseDefaultServiceProvider(static o =>
{
    o.ValidateScopes = true;
    o.ValidateOnBuild = true;
});
```

Thanks to "TheDoomDestroyer" for the clarification.

UPD. Tests

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Start");
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
services.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();
Run(services);
Collect();

static void Run(IServiceCollection services)
{
    using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(new ServiceProviderOptions
    {
        ValidateOnBuild = false,
        ValidateScopes = false
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        RunScope(serviceProvider);
        Collect();
    }

    var singletonService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISingletonService>();
    Console.WriteLine($"Singleton: {singletonService.Test()}");
    Collect();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        RunScope(serviceProvider);
        Collect();
    }
}

static void RunScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedService>();
    Console.WriteLine(scopedService.Test());
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static void Collect()
{
    Console.WriteLine("CG collect");
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Console.WriteLine("CG collected");
}

public interface ISingletonService
{
    string Test();
}
public class SingletonService : ISingletonService
{
    private readonly IScopedService _scopedService;

    public SingletonService(IScopedService scopedService)
    {
        _scopedService = scopedService;
        Console.WriteLine("SingletonService was created");
    }

    public string Test() => _scopedService.Test();
    
    ~SingletonService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Singleton service was collected");
    }
}

public interface IScopedService
{
    string Test();
}
public class ScopedService : IScopedService
{
    private static int StaticServiceNumber = 0;
    private readonly int _serviceNumber = 0;
    public ScopedService()
    {
        _serviceNumber = StaticServiceNumber;
        StaticServiceNumber++;
        Console.WriteLine($"ScopedService {_serviceNumber} was created");
    }

    public string Test() => $"Test from scoped service {_serviceNumber}";

    ~ScopedService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Scoped service {_serviceNumber} was collected");
    }
}
```

```
Start
ScopedService 0 was created
Test from scoped service 0
CG collect
Scoped service 0 was collected
CG collected
ScopedService 1 was created
Test from scoped service 1
CG collect
Scoped service 1 was collected
CG collected
ScopedService 2 was created
Test from scoped service 2
CG collect
Scoped service 2 was collected
CG collected
ScopedService 3 was created
SingletonService was created
Singleton: Test from scoped service 3
CG collect
CG collected
ScopedService 4 was created
Test from scoped service 4
CG collect
Scoped service 4 was collected
CG collected
ScopedService 5 was created
Test from scoped service 5
CG collect
Scoped service 5 was collected
CG collected
ScopedService 6 was created
Test from scoped service 6
CG collect
Scoped service 6 was collected
CG collected
CG collect
CG collected
```